# Doctrine 2 Generates SQL from Entity Metas not explicit NULL on attributes nullable=false on SQLServer

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, doctrine-orm

I'm creating my db script from entity metas, using `$sqlSchema = $this->tool->createSchema($this->metas);` and this method execute the SQL correctly, but for some reason the attributes set as `nullable=false`, it doesn't explicit sets NULL.

Generate from Doctrine:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
name INT NOT NULL,
other_column INT,
other_column2 NVARCHAR(2500),
);
```

What i need:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
name INT NOT NULL,
other_column INT NULL,
other_column2 NVARCHAR(2500) NULL,
);
```

This script when i execute from doctrine, all columns who don't have NULL explicit its puts NOT NULL. If i execute from a client tool its works fine. And f i change the connection type to MySQL its executes fine, setting NULL and NOT NULL correctly.

I'm using Doctrine 2.3.4 and SQLServer 2012.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is probably relate to a missing information in the entity definition.

You should try to define a **default value** (in your case null) either in the entity annotation or in the yml, depending on your definition style. Also you should mark you field as nullable via *nullable=true* statement.

*Annotation example:*

```
@ORM\Column(name="baz", [...], nullable=true, options={"default":null})
```

*yml example:*

```
Entity\Entity_name:
    type: entity
    table: table_name
    fields: 
        field_name:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            options:
                default: null
```

hope it helps,
regards.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but i already did it and nothing change, it doesnt set "NULL" in front my columns... My version is 2.3.4, and i needed to implement a new driver "dblib" to make linux + doctrine + sqlserver understand each other. 
`/**
     * @var string $st_name
     * @Column(name="st_name", type="string", nullable=true, length=20, options={"default":null})
     */
    private $st_name;`

Comment: I'm thinking to create the ALTER TABLE script on my own with the metas and then execute after the createSchema.